# form is not doing submit after calling function return false only one time

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, form-submit

I am trying to control form submitting after validating user input 
the user must select at least one radio otherwise the form wouldn't submit

the first part is working very fine, if the user haven't select any radio input I call

```
$('form').submit(function () { return false });
```

else if he selected something I will call

```
$('form').submit();
```

but it is not submitting

```
function validateSelection() {
        var temp = false;
        $('.lang-radio > input[type=radio]').each(function () {
            if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                temp |= $(this).is(':checked')
            };
        });
        if (temp != 1) {
            $('form').submit(function () { return false });
            $('.high-light').effect("shake");
        }
        else {
            $('form').submit();
        }
    }
```

I am calling the function validateSelection from OnClientClick="validateSelection();"
I am using asp.net webforms

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do

```
$('form').submit(function () { return false });
```

you are attaching an event handler to the `submit` event. Thus, if this line executes first, then every time you do `$('form').submit();`, the event handler will be triggered and return false and not submit.

If the .Net control is a submit button, you can simply replace the first line with `return false` (Edit: and change it to `OnClientClick="return validateSelection();"`), otherwise you can remove it completely.

Comment: I have actually done that after a second thought about the way it is working and it is now working with me

Answer (score 1):

1) Remove OnClientClick="validateSelection();" from your form

2) Give class="validateForm" to your form

3) put following js code in you are js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
                        $('.validateForm').on('submit',function(){
                            var ckradio = $(this).find('[type=radio]:checked');
                            if(ckradio.length == 0){
                                return false;
                            }else{
                                return true;
                            }
                        });
                    });
```